# C++ function runs in windows perfectly but not linux?

Tags: c++, linux

I am trying to write a simple c++ function `sleep(int millisecond)` that will sleep the program for user-specific millisecond.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void sleep(unsigned int mseconds) {
    clock_t goal = mseconds + clock();
    while (goal > clock());
}

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World !" << endl;
    sleep(3000);
    cout << "Hello World 2" << endl;
}
```

The `sleep()` function works perfectly when I run this code on windows but doesn't work on Linux. Can anyone figure it out what's wrong with my code?

Comment: that's not sleep. it's busy wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use build-in `sleep()` function which takes pospond time as seconds not in milliseconds and have to include `unistd.h` standard library as build-in  `sleep()` function is defined under this library.

Try it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World !" << endl;
    sleep(3);   //wait for 3 seconds
    cout << "Hello World 2" << endl;
}
```

:P

Answer (score 9):

I don't know why everyone is dancing around your question instead of answering it.

You are attempting to implement your own sleep-like function, and your implementation, while it does busy wait instead of sleeping in the kernelspace (meaning that processor will be "actively" running code to sleep your program, instead of telling the machine your program is sleeping and it should run other code), is just fine.

The problem is that `clock()` is not required to return milliseconds. `clock()` will return system time/process time elapsed in ticks from epoch. What unit that time will take depends on the implementation.

For instance, on my machine, this is what the man page says:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> The clock() function determines the amount of processor time used since
>   the invocation of the calling process, measured in CLOCKS_PER_SECs of a
>   second.
>
> RETURN VALUES
>
> The clock() function returns the amount of time used unless an error
>   occurs, in which case the return value is -1.
>
> SEE ALSO
>
> getrusage(2), clocks(7)
>
> STANDARDS
>
> The clock() function conforms to ISO/IEC 9899:1990 (``ISO C90'') and
>   Version 3 of the Single UNIX Specification (``SUSv3'') **which requires
>   CLOCKS_PER_SEC to be defined as one million**.

As you can see from the bolded part, a tick is one-one-millionth of a second, aka a microsecond (not a millisecond). To "sleep" for 3 seconds, you'll need to call your `sleep(3000000)` and not `sleep(3000)`.

Answer (score 2):

With C++11 you can use [`sleep_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for).

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

void sleep(unsigned int mseconds) {
    std::chrono::milliseconds dura( mseconds);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for( dura );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard C API for milliseconds on Linux so you will have to use [`usleep`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep). POSIX `sleep` takes seconds.